# How can I remove delta-homes.com from browsers?

Tags: search, registry, malware

whenever I open my browsers, delta-homes.com tab is added to the browser.  I try to remove delta-homes.com in all of my browsers(IE,FF,chrome,Opera) by registry in run > regedit, about:config in firefox, changing home page and search engine defaults and reset Internet Explorer(and reinstall it from "Turn Windows features on or off")....! but it isn't removed. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) to clean up your system...

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so useful :)

Answer (score 1):

For IE. Goto -> Tools tab -> manage Add-onns -> serach provider. In right side find delta home and right click and select remove.

For crome  goto settings->manage serch engine -> select delta home and remove it with click on cross sign from right side. and click Done. now Gone delta home.

or you can remove it with this tools [Adware remover Tool](http://www.techsupportall.com/Adware-Removal-Tool.exe) .

Comment: Again go to there -> search provider and click on google crome and make it default.